# CAShapeLayer line's rounded corners

Tags: ios, swift3, cashapelayer

I want to draw diagonal line with rounded corners in view.
My code:

```
class DiagonalView: UIView {

// MARK: - Public Properties

@IBInspectable var fillColor: UIColor = UIColor.white {
    didSet {
        self.diagonalLayer.strokeColor = fillColor.cgColor
        self.redraw()
    }
}

@IBInspectable var lineWidth: CGFloat = 1 {
    didSet {
        self.diagonalLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
        self.redraw()
    }
}

// MARK: - Private Properties

private var diagonalLayer: CAShapeLayer = {
    let layer = CAShapeLayer()
    layer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    layer.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    layer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
    layer.lineWidth = 1
    return layer
}()

// MARK: - Constructors

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.layer.addSublayer(self.diagonalLayer)
    self.setupPath()
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.setupPath()
}

// MARK: - Private methods

private func redraw() {
    self.setNeedsDisplay()
}

private func setupPath() {
    let startPoint = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width, y: 0)
    let endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.frame.height)
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.move(to: startPoint)
    path.addLine(to: endPoint)
    path.close()
    self.diagonalLayer.path = path.cgPath
}

}
```

Line position is right. But corners are not rounded.
Result:

[image]

The code looks good but think I mess something... Any suggestions?

Comment: I haven't tried to do get rounded end-caps on a shape layer before. It seems strange that the shape layer has a line cap style separate from the path's line cap style. What if you set the line cap style to rounded on the CGPath that you install into your shape layer?

Answer (score 5):

I think I found the problem. The docs say:

The line cap style specifies the shape of the endpoints of an open path when stroked.

You are closing your path. Leave it open.